# Why does GetFullPathName return the working directory?

Tags: c++, winapi, path

I stumbled upon a behavior of [`GetFullPathName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (through the use of [`QFileInfo::canonicalFilePath()`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qfileinfo.html#canonicalFilePath)) that I don't quite understand: when I call this function with a string composed of the current drive letter and a colon, it returns the path of the current working directory, while I would expect the path to the drive letter.

The following code exemplifies what I'm talking about:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string canonicalFilePath(const char *path)
{
    static const std::size_t BufferSize = 300;
    char canonicalPath[BufferSize];

    GetFullPathName(path, BufferSize, canonicalPath, 0);

    return std::string(canonicalPath);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    SetCurrentDirectory("C:/some/path");
    std::cout << "In C:" << '\n';
    std::cout << "  C   -> " << canonicalFilePath("C")   << '\n'
              << "  C:  -> " << canonicalFilePath("C:")  << '\n'
              << "  C:/ -> " << canonicalFilePath("C:/") << '\n'
              << "  D   -> " << canonicalFilePath("D")   << '\n'
              << "  D:  -> " << canonicalFilePath("D:")  << '\n'
              << "  D:/ -> " << canonicalFilePath("D:/") << '\n';

    SetCurrentDirectory("D:/other/path");
    std::cout << "In D:" << '\n';
    std::cout << "  C   -> " << canonicalFilePath("C")   << '\n'
              << "  C:  -> " << canonicalFilePath("C:")  << '\n'
              << "  C:/ -> " << canonicalFilePath("C:/") << '\n'
              << "  D   -> " << canonicalFilePath("D")   << '\n'
              << "  D:  -> " << canonicalFilePath("D:")  << '\n'
              << "  D:/ -> " << canonicalFilePath("D:/") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
In C:
  C   -> C:\some\path\C      // ok
  C:  -> C:\some\path        // ? why not C:\ ?
  C:/ -> C:\                 // ok
  D   -> C:\some\path\D      // ok
  D:  -> D:\                 // ok
  D:/ -> D:\                 // ok
In D:
  C   -> D:\other\path\C     // ok
  C:  -> C:\                 // ok
  C:/ -> C:\                 // ok
  D   -> D:\other\path\D     // ok
  D:  -> D:\other\path       // ? why not D:\ ?
  D:/ -> D:\                 // ok
```

Is this behavior normal? In [`GetFullPathName` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is stated that

> If you specify "U:" the path returned is "U:\"

Why is this not the case if "U" is the current drive letter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the
> backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the
> current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that
> the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending
> on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory"
> operation on that disk.
>
> Examples of this format are as follows:
>
> 1. "C:tmp.txt" refers to a file named "tmp.txt" in the current directory
>    on drive C.
> 2. "C:tempdir\tmp.txt" refers to a file in a subdirectory to
>    the current directory on drive C.

Answer (score 1):

It has been like that since the old DOS days. If your current directory is on drive `D:`, then `D:` will always be your current directory. The case talked about in the documentation is when you pass a drive *different* from where your current directory is.